# How to tell a remote host is Windows or Linux in Ansible?

Tags: windows, ansible, winrm

I know Ansible runs on Linux but if WinRm is used to manage Windows system remotely. Is there anyway I can tell (detect) if a remote host is Windows and not Linux?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just read the `ansible_system` variable. It will contain "Linux" on a Linux system and "Win32NT" on Windows.

There are other "facts" you can inspect to get even more precision. You can see an example of these in the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html)

Comment: The question is that the 'system' is the remote host. So from ansible controller to connect to that remote host, connection must be 'winrm'. Without specifying the connection type it won't reach out to a Windows remote host.

Comment: @user12363702 You will be able to know the system in the middle of an execution containing mixed targets to decide e.g. which set of tasks to play. But knowing this information implies gathering facts, hence connecting to the remote target after declaring it in your inventory, which implies knowing (or dynamically getting through an inventory plugin like they exist for aws, gcp, vsphere, custom made...) a minimum of info about your host like it's network address and the connection type.

Comment: That being said: if you only have the address, a quickNdirty first approach could be to test from localhost if port 22 is opened and if not modify with `add_host` the in memory inventory to change the connection type that will be used in the next play in the same playbook.

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator. But the problem is that port 22 can't be the indicator of Linux OS. In Windows 10 you can install OpenSSH server and utilize this port as well. Some SFTP on Windows can use this port too.

Comment: @user12363702 Perhaps you could tell us what are you trying to accomplish, elaborating on "tell". For the common use cases I can think of, you don't need to determine the host OS beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but **this gives you a way to use a single role to do tasks for windows and linux**.
Assuming you have a windows and a linux server configured correctly to receive ansible commands.
In your `inventory` you can have the following:

```
[windows]
10.0.0.2
[linux]
10.100.0.2
```

Then create a file `group_vars/windows.yml` (group_vars is a folder, and windows.yml the file - The name must match the group in the config):

```yaml
ansible_connection: winrm
# The option below is if you have not setup certs for winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

ansible_user: ADMIN     # <- replace with your configured user
ansible_password: PASS  # <- replace with your configured pass
```

> If you use group_vars folder, you can also create an `all.yml` and a `linux.yml` to add more variables.
> Ansible looks at the name of the file in group_vars folder and applies it to the group in the inventory.
> Or you can store the variables inside your inventory with [windows:vars]

Then in your role, you can have something like:

```bash
.
├── ...
└── tasks
    ├── linux.yml
    ├── main.yml
    └── win32nt.yml
```

And your `main.yml` can be like this:

```yaml
- name: Do whatever
  include_tasks: '{{ansible_system|lower}}.yml'
```

> If you want to be more specific, you can use: `ansible_os_family`, which will give you: 'Windows', 'Debian', 'RedHat', ...

Those are basic steps but should give you a starting point where you can improve it for your need.

A sample where this is useful is if you have a role that installs Java JDK and you and to have a single role for that.

---

Reference:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-in-multiple-groups

[Guide Winrm](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html)

[Windows setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html)